# How to hook on mouseclick in a QGraphicsView?

Tags: python, pyqt5, mouseevent

I am somewhat new in PyQt. I have a python PyQt5 code with a simple dialog window created with the designer and within the dialog I have a QGraphicsView. In this view there is only one image in a QGraphicsScene.

Now I want to run a code when the user clicks with the  mouse over the image but I don't know exactly how to do that.

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
def setupUi(self, Dialog):
...
        self.gv_1_H = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)

...
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("ui/d0.png")
        scene.addPixmap(pixmap)
        self.gv_1_H.setScene(scene)
        self.gv_1_H.setSizeAdjustPolicy( QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents )
...
```

I could not find any hint after searching for an hour on the web...

Any hint?
Thanks

Comment: I can't provide since I don't know what to do. Shall I use 'connect' or override an event?  What is the preferred way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouse events for Qt widgets are protected functions and you need to subclass the widget you want to react to them and override those functions.

To avoid subclassing you could alternatively install an eventFilter to react to them, but its not something I'd suggest for this scenario.

```
class MyScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyScene, self).__init__()
        self.pixmapItem = self.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ui/d0.png"))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.scenePos() in self.pixmapItem.sceneBoundingRect():
            print('image clicked!')
        else:
            super(MyScene, self).mousePressEvent(event)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        # ...
        scene = MyScene()
        self.gv_1_H.setScene(scene)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very userful. I was struggeling with trying to install an eventFilter, but it seemed way too complex for this simple task....  then I tried to simply assign a new function to the self.gv_1_H.mousePressEvent = myMousePressEvent, but this didn't work either without throwing any exception or error.